# When dealing with the absence of libomp Error when import LightGBM, an error occurred on Brew installing

Tags: macos, homebrew, lightgbm

on Mac OS I was trying command as following on Terminal:

```
$brew install libomp

**Error**: cmake: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/cmake.rb:1: syntax error, unexpected <<
<<<<<<< HEAD
^~
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula/cmake.rb:84: syntax error, unexpected ===, expecting end-of-input
=======
^~~
```

when dealing with

```
...
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/lightgbm/lib_lightgbm.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a merge conflict in your local clone of `homebrew/core`. Run this command to [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your local changes:

```
$ git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) stash
```

Once you've done this, try running `brew install libomp` again.